# Valgrind won't detect buffer overflow

Tags: c, valgrind, buffer-overflow

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{     
    char buf[8];
    sprintf(buf,"AAAA%3s","XXssssssssXXXsssssXXX");
    printf("%s\n",buf);
}
```

I expected valgrind to detect a buffer overflow with the above code. But it does not report any errors or warnings. Do I need to enable any special flags for that?

Comment: With a recent `gcc` or `clang`  compiler, you could compile with `-Wall -g -fsanitize=address` and it might give a message at runtime. BTW `sprintf` is intrinsically unsafe and should not be used. Use `snprintf` or `asprintf`

Comment: See our CheckPointer tool; it will find many memory errors that valgrind cannot. http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/MemorySafety

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From [Valgrind Tutorial](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~bart/537/valgrind.html)

**What valgrind is NOT**

> Although valgrind is an extremely useful program, it will not miraculously tell you about every memory bug in your program. There are several limitations that you should keep in mind. It does not do bounds checking on stack/static arrays ..